# How to change black to white

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixlr

I know how to make the background transparent. What I can't find is a one or two click way to change black to white. I ended up having to spend over ten minutes trying to manually change a bunch of black pixels to white. I have other icons I want to be white. I'm trying to use a free tool like Pixlr but could install trial of Photoshop if needed.

[image: Tool]

Comment: Hey Tim! Welcome to GraphicDesign. What resources have you looked at? This is a pretty simple thing to do if you research it a bit

Comment: I googled change color and only found stuff like https://support.pixlr.com/hc/en-us/articles/210065767-How-to-use-the-color-replacement-tool- which is what forced to me to do time consuming black pixels.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Blending Option is best for changing colors of your Image If the background is transperant.

with the help of blending options you could change the color of image or icon into any color

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Double click or right click on your layer and select blending options. A layer style popup will open.
2. From the Layer style menu Select Color overlay and pick your color. Smart and easy

[image]

Comment: these are not blending options, it's the Color Overlay layer style

Comment: @Luciano it comes under blending options...Layer style is just one option of blending mode

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> is the quickest way to do it. It just inverts all black pixels to white. It will also switch other colors to their complementary.

Answer (score -2):

CTRL+Backspace fills the background with main color, Alt+Backspace - Additional color

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The Asker wants to fill his black *foreground* pixels with white.